# PDF Error Opening Error Retrieved From Database to Virtual Folder

Tags: sql-server, pdf, binary-data, virtual-directory

I am trying to Retrieve Binary Data [PDF] From SQL Server to My Virtual Directory:

```
 string filePaths = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TempPDF/");
```

And I have the following code to Write Data Into filePath, its downloading fine but when I am trying to open in PDF its giving me error. "Adobe Reader could not open ***"FileName.pdf" because it is either not supported or because file has been damaged"***
My Code :

```
string last = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
if (last == "pdf")
                {
                    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filePaths+fileName, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew )) 
                    {           // use a binary writer to write the bytes to disk
                        using (System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs))
                        {
                            bw.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
                            //bw.Write(Data);
                            bw.Flush();
                            bw.Close();
                         }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Use the [DATALENGTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) function to check the size of the binary data, then check the file size and make sure your process is writing all the data.

Comment: Solved the code was absolutely fine, It was just **GZipStream** Compressed. 
And I used: 

    static byte[] Decompress(byte[] ComData)
        {
            using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(ComData))
            using (var zipStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);

                zipStream.Close();
                resultStream.Close();
                return resultStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
Many Thanks ...